# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un campo o botón solo con tabulador con css y materialize?

Tags: css, materialize, botón

Intento realizar una operación para imprimir un nombre al darle clic en un botón, estoy trabajando con css y materialize. Mi pregunta es al escribir la entrada y cambiar con el tabulador al botón no lo enfoca y se pasa a la siguiente operación.

¿De que manera puedo enfocar el botón sin que tenga que saltarlo solo con el tabulador?

```
<div class="container">
          <p class="z-depth-5">
         <fieldset>
            <h3>Un Hola</h3>
               <form>
                  Introduce tu nombre <input type="text" id="nombreCompleto"><br>
                  <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-ligh blue" id="unHola"><i class="material-icons">Hola</i></a>
                  <!-- <input type="button" value="Hola" id="unHola"> -->

                  <span class="ay" id="resultadoNombre"></span>
               </form>
         </fieldset>
         </div>

         <br><br>
```

el ejemplo se visualiza de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quizá puede usar Transitions de Materialize a modo de que termine de responder, lo siguiente a responder salga después, como también puedes usar JavaScript con el evento **onclick** , en fin pienso que si necesitarás JavaScript.
Saludos

Comment: te agradezco por la información, buscare como poder implementaro